# Mostrar ProgressBar durante ejecucion de llamada a API en Android

Tags: java, android, progressbar

Tengo un fragment con un formulario y un botón que al clickarlo se realiza una llamada sobre una API.

Al hacer click en el botón quiero que una ProgressBar se haga visible mientras se ejecuta un bucle en el que se valida la respuesta de la API.

El problema es que el ProgressBar no se hace visible hasta que termina el bucle, cuando la sentencia para que se haga visible es MUCHO ANTES.

Este es el código del clickListener:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.send_soporte) {

            //--------------- AQUI SE HACE VISIBLE ---------------//
            view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_soporte).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            EditText soporte = view.findViewById(R.id.cuerpo_soporte);
            String soporte_str = soporte.getText().toString();


            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            ticket.setNombre(usuario.getUsuario());
            ticket.setCorreo(usuario.getEmail());
            ticket.setCuerpo(soporte_str);

            //--------------- AQUI SE EJECUTA EL BUCLE ---------------//
            int status = sendTicket(ticket);
            //--------------- AQUI SE TERMINA EL BUCLE ---------------//

            if(status == 1){
                printTicketInfo("Mensaje enviado con éxito.");
                soporte.setText("");
            } else if( status == -1){
                printTicketInfo("El mensaje debe contener entre 20 y 1000 caracteres.");
            }else if( status == -2 || status == 0){
                printTicketInfo("No se ha podido contactar con el servidor. Revise su conexión a internet e inténtelo de nuevo.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has probado con hacer visible el progressbar antes del primer if? y luego hacerlo invisible de nuevo dentro del if de status == 1 que asumo que es que fue exitosa la ejecución del servicio del API, claro también cuando da error.

Comment: Si, he probado. Y no se muestra hasta que el bucle termina.

Comment: hay algun error en el logcat?

Comment: Nada. He probado a poner logs a la vez que se muestra y se oculta, y los logs van al tiempo que deberían. Pero el progressbar no se muestra hasta que en los logs pone... ocultando.

Comment: ¿Que código tienes cuando imprimes en el Log "ocultando"?

Comment: Acabo de estar leyendo por stackoverflow en inglés y parece ser que en los eventos onClick se bloquea el UI, por lo que no se produce ningún cambio hasta que termina el onClick. Puede que sea eso lo que pasa...

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier cambio visual no es rendereado al usuario hasta que terminan de ejecutarse los metodos de android, en tu caso el `onClick`.

Para poder realizar cambios en la interfaz grafica, primero tendras que mostrar un `ProgressBar` en 0%, y luego iniciar un proceso asincrono que actualize el progreso de la `ProgressBar`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.send_soporte) {
        ProgressBar progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_soporte)
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        EditText soporte = view.findViewById(R.id.cuerpo_soporte);
        String soporte_str = soporte.getText().toString();

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setNombre(usuario.getUsuario());
        ticket.setCorreo(usuario.getEmail());
        ticket.setCuerpo(soporte_str);

        new TicketAsyncTask(soporte, progressBar).execute(ticket);
    }
}
```

En tu caso, podrias implementar un [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) que periodicamente actualiza el `ProgressBar`:

```
private class TicketAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Ticket, Integer, Integer> {
    private EditText soporte;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public TicketAsyncTask(EditText soporte, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.soporte = soporte;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(Ticket... tickets) {
        // Logica que interactua con el ticket y actualiza el progreso

        while (condicion) {
            // calcular progreso y modificar condicion

            publishProgress(progreso);

            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }

        return status;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long status) {
        if(status == 1){
            //printTicketInfo("Mensaje enviado con éxito.");
            soporte.setText("");
        } else if( status == -1){
            //printTicketInfo("El mensaje debe contener entre 20 y 1000 caracteres.");
        }else if( status == -2 || status == 0){
            //printTicketInfo("No se ha podido contactar con el servidor. Revise su conexión a internet e inténtelo de nuevo.");
        }
    }
 }
```

Segun tus requerimientos, probablemente no sea necesario actualizar el progreso del ProgressBar, por lo que solo habria que volverla a esconder en el `onPostExecute` de `TicketAsyncTask`. La idea es que cualquier cambio a la UI se realize en los metodos de `onProgressUpdate` o `onPostExecute`.

Ojo, sugiero que pases al constructor del proceso asincrono elementos de la UI, pero esto es solo con proposito demostrativo. No estoy seguro si sea de las mejores practicas por temas de memoria y Garbage Collection.